# How to close the position partillay

Tags: pine-script, trading

could you please help to making the split close position when reached to goal price?

for example ->

1000 $ -> enter price long position

1100 $ -> when 10% raise, close the 20% position in total enter volume

1200 $ -> when 20% raise, close the 20 % position in total enter volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use :

```
strategy.close(id, comment, qty, qty_percent, alert_message, immediately)
```

with qty_percent = 20 for example.
You can have more information in the manual : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}close](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dclose)